# How to divide html page in two columns?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to divide my html page into two columns. One column is supposed to be filled by an image and other by text. I am facing below issues:

1. Columns not occupying the exact 50-50 width.
2. There is a thin margin from left before the image starts. Need to remove that margin.
3. There is a huge gap between the two columns.

It will be really helpful if someone can look at this code and suggest corrections:

```css
.container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.thin-black-border {
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 05px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.header {
  font: 200 80px'Oleo Script', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div style="width:100%; height: 100px;background-color:green" class="bg-faded">
  <!-- Main Div -->
  <h1 class="text-center header">Madhubala</h1>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:50%;" class="container">
  <img src="https://nehamalude.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/madhubala.jpg" class="thin-black-border" />
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:50%; background-color:red; ">
  Right
</div>
```

Comment: Use bootstrap : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_stacked_to_horizontal.asp

Comment: You don't need to use bootstrap to create a 2 column layout.

Answer (score 13):

You can simply use table : 
Method 1:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>You can add content here</td>
    <td>You can add content here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Method 2:

```html
<div style="display:block; width:100%;">
  <div style="width:50%; float: left; display: inline-block;">Your content</div>
  <div style="width:50%; float: left; display: inline-block;">Your content</div>
</div>
```

Method 3 ( Using Flex ) :

```html
    <div class="flexbox-container" style="display:flex;">
        <div class="sidebar" style="flex:1;">Test column 1</div>
        <div class="main" style="flex:1;">Test column 2</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the point of setting `display:inline-block` to floated elements whose `display` [computes to](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) `block` anyway?

Comment: method 3 worked perfectly for me : thank you :) happy coding

Answer (score 4):

```css
body{
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.thin-black-border {
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 05px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.header {
  font: 200 80px'Oleo Script', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.main-wrap{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.main-wrap > div{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div style="width:100%; height: 100px;background-color:green" class="bg-faded">
  <!-- Main Div -->
  <h1 class="text-center header">Madhubala</h1>
</div>
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://nehamalude.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/madhubala.jpg" class="thin-black-border" />
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:red; ">
    Right
  </div>

</div>
```

How about using `display: flex`?

Comment: I would add:
`.container img {
    ...
    box-sizing: border-box;
}` to respect the image border

Answer (score 0):

Add width = 100% to the image.

Use a css reset to remove the margins

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

see jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ssohvr45/2/